# WordPress DB with Android app using Retrotfit

Tags: php, android, json, wordpress, retrofit

I am working on Android app using Retrofit. I have a website on WordPress.

I am passing data from Android using Retrofit to a PHP file on my server, and in the PHP file I am writing a query and get the result in JSON; I get that JSON in Android.

Now I want to sign up and log in. How can I save the password to the WordPress database user table?

I have used this before for password encryption, which was not a WordPress DB.

```
function encrypt_password($password, $key){
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(
    mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC),
    MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM
);

$encrypted = base64_encode(
    $iv .
    mcrypt_encrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
        hash('sha256', $key, true),
        $password,
        MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
        $iv
    )
);
return $encrypted;}
```

Comment: instead of giving negative point. can anyone tell me the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Better if you can create a new data table for store these kind of data instead of using existing Wordpress user table. You can use native Wordpress functions and global $wpdb object to achieve this. Look at the sample code below.

```
function updatePassword($plainPassword, $userId){
    global $wpdb;
    $newPass = wp_hash_password($plainPassword);
    return $wpdb->update('my_table_name', array(
        'user_password' => $newPass
    ), array('user_id' => $userId));
}

updatePassword('mynewpass', 1);
```

**References:**

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_password

Comment: user can signup from website and also from app.